# How to prove that $\gcd(t^n-1,t^m-1)=t^{\gcd(n,m)}-1 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)

Let $t$ be an element in any domain where gcd's exist. Then if $m,n$ are positive integer,prove that:      $\gcd(t^n-1,t^m-1)=t^{\gcd(n,m)}-1 $