# Powers of a greatest common denominator

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)

> Given $n \ge 1$ and $s, t \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $s \ge t$, prove that $$\gcd(n^{s} - 1, n^{t} - 1) = n^{\gcd(s, t)} - 1$$

I've been looking at this problem for a while now, but I'm not certain where to begin. Can induction on $s$ be used to prove the result for $n \geq 1$ since $s \ge t$?

Comment: What remainder do you get when you divide $n^s-1$ by $n^t-1$? Show that if $a=bq+r$ then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$, apply it to this situation, and compare to the Euclidean algorithm for finding $\gcd(s,t)$.

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235641/how-to-prove-that-gcdtn-1-tm-1-t-gcdn-m-1?

Comment: And a bit more generally, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262130/how-to-prove-gcdam-bm-an-bn-a-gcdm-n-b-gcdm-n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\  mod\ any\ d\!:\ \ n^s,n^t\equiv 1\iff ord(n)\ |\ s,t\iff ord(n)\ |\ (s,t)\iff n^{(s,t)}\equiv 1 $

Therefore $\rm\ d\ |\ n^s\!-\!1,\:n^t\!-\!1 \iff d\ |\ n^{(s,t)}\!-\!1.\ $  Therefore $\,\rm \{n^s\!-\!1,\:n^t\!-\!1\}\,$ and  $\rm\, n^{(s,t)}\!-1\,$  have the same set D of common divisors, hence they have the same *greatest* common divisor (= max D).

Comment: Did you notice that your friend Bill had already posted an answer to the question I flagged as a duplicate?